# OCPsoft Rewrite Rule no longer works after Update from 1.0.5 to 1.1.0

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting, ocpsoft-rewrite

When updating [OCPsoft Rewrite](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/) from Version 1.0.5.Final to 1.1.0.Final the following Rule no longer works and I don't know how to fix it:

```
.addRule(
    Join.path("/{i}/{d}")
        .where("i").matches("[-_a-zA-Z0-9~*]{8}")
        .where("d").matches("[-_a-zA-Z0-9~*]{32}")
        .to("/resources/html/user/doSomething.html?i={i}&d={d}")
)
```

In the Rewrite [changelog](https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) there is one point that could help you help me:

> Configuration strings are now literal. Regular expressions must be configured through a >parameter such as: `.defineRule().when(Path.matches("/{*}").where("*").matches(".*"))`

The exception I get is the following one:

```
Exception starting filter OCPsoft Rewrite Filter
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.config.rule.Join.where(Join.java:199)
        at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.config.rule.Join.where(Join.java:47)
        at com.myapp.util.RewriteConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(RewriteConfigurationProvider.java:39)
        ...
```

Comment: PS. Sorry for the late answer :) Holidays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following did the trick, I just had to reorder the join clauses:

```
.addRule(
    Join.path("/{i}/{d}")
        .to("/resources/html/user/doSomething.html")
        .where("i").matches("[-_a-zA-Z0-9~*]{8}")
        .where("d").matches("[-_a-zA-Z0-9~*]{32}")
        .withRequestBinding();
)
```

Thanks to Lincoln, who figured this out and answered my question on the Rewrite support forums.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. that does look like a bug, I'll try to reproduce this, but you shouldn't need to re-define `{i}` and `{d}` in the target URL. Join will handle that for you automatically if you use request binding, like so:

```
.addRule(
   Join.path("/{i}/{d}")
    .where("i").matches("[-_a-zA-Z0-9~*]{8}")
    .where("d").matches("[-_a-zA-Z0-9~*]{32}")
    .to("/resources/html/user/doSomething.html").withRequestBinding();
)
```

I'm guessing if you do that, your problem will go away. You can also use `.withInboundCorrection()` if you'd like to redirect requests for the old `.html` URL to the new URL.

If you still have a problem with this, please post on the support forums and we'll get it figured out :)

Sorry you had trouble, hopefully it won't be trouble any more :)